# php define password , username in the script, security

Tags: php, security, passwords

```
<?php

   $Admin=Array
(
    "Username" => "Admin",
    "Password" => "Admin"
);

$User=Array
(
    "Username" => "User",
    "Password" => "User"
);

$AllUsers=Array
(
    $Admin,
    $User
);

?>
```

So my first question is: How secure is this (Since I just need two users on my website, I see no need in using a database)? I'm asking this because I'm wondering how a person should get this (unless it has access to my computer when I'm logging in) since the php script is executed before the browser gets it. And if there's a security issue, how can I solve it? Furthermore I've read already about encrypting but I do not see any sense in doing something like this

```
<?php
   $Admin=Array
(
    "Username" => "Admin",
    "Password" => md5("something")
);

$User=Array
(
    "Username" => "User",
    "Password" => md5("somethingelse")
);

$AllUsers=Array
(
    $Admin,
    $User
);

?>
```

since a person does get the password as well if the person has access to the php script.

My last question is: Is there a way to download source files from a website? (Since that would give the person downloading this the php script and therefore the password)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using `md5` like that inside the code doesn't add anything but overhead to your script, and is by no means secure. If you want it to be secure with the way you're doing (and also be secure to people looking at your code) make sure that you MD5 your password *BEFORE* putting it into the script (and remember to use a salt too!)

Comment: sounds quite senseful a shame that i haven't came up with that by myself. Thanks

Comment: please, use at least `crypt()` on the passwords with blowfish or sha512 an **different** random salt for each

Answer (score 3):

It is possible for someone to access and download a PHP file. It's not easy, and this would happen due to incorrect server configuration or other security failing points (for example a file download PHP script that has been poorly written)

A good option is to store the password file on the server in a location that your script can access, but it can not be accessed by your web server.

Even if you store your data in a database, someone could gain access to your database server (via bad PHP code, or other ways) and then do a brute force attack on the simple md5 hashes and figure out the password.

For a simple security, best bet is to just put the password file out of the web server's reach.

Comment: **and use an md5 salt** so even if your passwords were collected by an intruder, it'd take a very long time brute forcing passwords as they wouldn't be able to use existing md5 rainbow-tables.

Comment: like Michael already mentioned, but how to do this? ( for the folder structure read comment below Michael's answer). Thanks

Comment: @VGD Do you use your own server / local server or a web host, and what server software do you use? (Apache/IIS/etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the only way you can download the source code is if the server is poorly configured. However, as an additional security measure, you may want to consider putting the username and password in a separate folder outside of the Web root which can never be served up the user.

Comment: I understand what you mean by that but how to do this? For example I have on my webspace this folder structure: / (that had been there by default) and then there are the files (like index.htm). I do not see how to move a file in a folder so that no one can access it for sure? Would be nice of you to explain that a bit further. Thanks

Comment: You would either point your Web server at a subfolder within your site or move a file to some other directory and `include` it in your other script.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is configured right, there is no way to download the php script.

Additionally, since your passwords are plain text, there is no sense in encrypting them with `md5()`

I recommend using a database anyway, where you can use encryption.

Comment: but why using a database if there's no need for it? There have to be a way to just define it securly in the script.